# Prove weak derivative commutes with difference quotient

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$,$f:U\to \mathbb{R},f\in W^{1,p}(U)$. Let $\tau_{h,i}f(x)=\frac{f(x+he_i)-f(x)}{h},h>0$

Given any compact $V\subset U$, show there exists $h_0>0$ such that $D(\tau_{h,i}f)=\tau_{h,i}(Df)$, for $h<h_0$

---

I try to prove it by definition.

Let $h_0=\frac{1}{2}d(\partial U,V)>0,h<h_0$, let $\phi\in C^1_c(V)\subset  C^1_c(U)$. Write $Df=(\frac{\partial}{x_j}f)_{j=1}^n$ then by definition, 
$$\int_Vf(x)\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x_j}=-\int_V\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_j} \phi(x)\tag{1}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
\int_V\tau_{h,i}f(x)\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x_j}&=\int_V\frac{f(x+he_i)-f(x)}{h}\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x_j}\\
&=\int_V\frac{f(x+he_i)}{h}\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x_j}-\frac{f(x)}{h}\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x_j}\\
&=\frac{1}{h}\left[\color{red}{-\int_V\frac{\partial f(x+he_i)}{\partial x_j} \phi(x)}+\int_V\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_j} \phi(x)\right]\\
&=-\int_V\tau_{h,i}\frac{ \partial f}{\partial x_j}(x) \phi(x)
\end{align}$$

Then we are done. But the problem is I don't know whether the red colored text is correct. Since by definition, to use $(1)$, the functions should be evaluated at the same point, while in my proof, they  are not.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's correct, maybe you would be more comfortable first passing the translation to the $\phi$ by a change of variables (notice that then $\phi(\cdot -he_i)$ still has compact support in $U$).